# Count the number of ways to place the identical balls in distinct bins

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**We have $6$ balls and $4$ bins.**

**a) 
Count the number of ways to place the identical balls in identical bins**

**b) 
Count the number of ways to place the identical balls in distinct bins**

a) My  solution looks like this:

1. $(6,0,0,0)$
2. $(2,4,0,0)$
3. $(3,3,0,0)$
4. $(5,1,0,0)$
5. $(2,3,1,0)$
6. $(2,2,2,0)$
7. $(4,1,1,0)$
8. $(3,1,1,1)$
9. $(2,1,1,2)$

And $9$ is the correct answer:

b) However im unsure of to think here. I guess for the first case $(6,0,0,0)$ there’s now 4 different ways to place the balls if the bins are distinct? But how many ways would there be for $(2,4,0,0)$, $(2,1,1,2)$ and so on? Is there a way to think here so that we can solve this problem?

$84$ should be the correct answer for b).

Comment: somewhat similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373202/distributing-identical-objects-to-identical-boxes

Comment: is there a way to solve part (a) without having to go about counting the different possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is easy to go from (a) to (b) or vice versa (unless the numbers are very small).

Part (b) is much easier.  It is solved by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) and has a closed-form solution (in fact, a binomial coefficient).

For part (a), we're talking about [integer partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) but with the additional restriction that the number of parts $\le 4$.  The wiki article includes the restricted case where the number of parts is exactly $k$, so I suppose you can sum over $k \in [1, 4]$.  Anyway, I don't think there is a general solution.  Here is a [related MSE thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1574794/how-many-solutions-does-the-equation-sum-i-1kx-i-c-have-given-that-th) which limits both the number of parts to $\le k$ and the size of each part to $\le d$.  So if we set $d=c$ so that each part is unlimited but the number of parts is still limited to $\le k$ then this becomes the OP question.

Comment: Thanks $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ worked for this problem. n = 6, k = 4

Comment: Yes, that's the standard stars-and-bars method for (b).

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** For $(4,1,1,0)$ case, we can choose the empty bin with $\binom{4}{1}$ and since balls are identical, we can put them to three bins with $\frac{3!}{2!} = 3$. Here, we are dividing it by $2!$ because balls are identical and we are putting same number of balls into two bins. So, in this specific case, there are $\binom{4}{1}\cdot\frac{3!}{2!} = 12$ different ways.

Now, can you find how many different ways in other cases?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for part (b):

Let the number of balls in each of the 4 distinct bins be $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ and $x_4$ respectively. The total number of balls (let the balls be represented by the character $\phi$) is $6\phi$ (as there are 6 balls, and each ball is $\phi$), therefore we can form the following equation-
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=6\phi$$

Solving this is straightforward- in how many ways can we write $6$ as the sum of 4 non-negative integers?

This is one way to solve it-

Let each ball be represented by the character $\phi$. Consider one case where there are 3 balls in the first bin, 1 ball in the second, third and the fourth bins, each. When I put this in the above equation:
$$\phi\phi\phi +\phi+\phi+\phi=6\phi$$
Note that we are NOT multiplying anything here.

The question now has simplified to- how many ways can we permute the elements of the following set:

$$\{\phi,\phi,\phi,\phi,\phi,\phi,+,+,+\}$$

This is one way of finding all the ways we can move the balls ($\phi$) into different boxes; i.e. we are just moving around the $\phi$'s and $+$'s in the above equation.

The answer is: 
$$\dfrac{9!}{6!\times3!}=84.$$

Comment: Does anyone know how we can apply this method for part (a) of the original question? I'm not sure how to go about solving it in this way.

Comment: There is no way to use the part (b) method to solve part (a). If you let $p(n,k)$ be the number of ways to put $n$ identical balls in $k$ identical boxes, then you can show $p(n,k) = p(n,k-1) + p(n-k,k)$, which lets you compute $p(n,k)$ by filling out at $n\times k$ table, using previously computed values to fill in later ones.